# Get first letter for first of multiple surnames in list starting with that letter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of employees for which i have to get the first letter, for the first surname that starts with that letter and add it as data.

```
                <ul class="org-list" >
                    <li class="org-list-item">
                        <span class="surname">AA</span> <span class="name">John</span>
                    </li>
                    <li class="org-list-item">
                        <span class="surname">AB</span> <span class="name">John</span>
                    </li>
                    <li class="org-list-item">
                        <span class="surname">AC</span> <span class="name">John</span>
                    </li>
                    <li class="org-list-item">
                        <span class="surname">BA</span> <span class="name">John</span>
                    </li>
                    <li class="org-list-item">
                        <span class="surname">BB</span> <span class="name">John</span>
                    </li>
                    <li class="org-list-item">
                        <span class="surname">CA</span> <span class="name">John</span>
                    </li>
                    <li class="org-list-item">
                        <span class="surname">CB</span> <span class="name">John</span>
                    </li>
                    <li class="org-list-item">
                        <span class="surname">CC</span> <span class="name">John</span>
                    </li>
                </ul>
```

From this list `<li>` items that have surnames AA, BA, CA should have a data attribute `data-surname="A"` or `data-surname="B"`, `data-surname="C"`

How can i extract those letters and add them as data?

I literally don't know how to start it so i don't have any code to post. Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either do it by using [jQuery Data Method](https://api.jquery.com/data/), which is not visible to DOM browser, or just add a `data-surname` attribute.

**E.g.**

```js
$(function() {
  var assignedSurname = [];
  $('.org-list-item > .surname').each(function(i, elem) {
    var $elem = $(elem);
    var surnameInitial = $elem.text()[0];
    if (assignedSurname.indexOf(surnameInitial) === -1) {
      var $liParent = $elem.parent('li');
      $liParent.attr('data-surname', surnameInitial);

      assignedSurname.push(surnameInitial);

      // Or as jquery data attribute, which is not visible to DOM browser.
      //$liParent.data('surname', surnameInitial);
    }
  });
  
  $('li.org-list-item[data-surname]').each(function(i, elem) {
     console.log($(elem).attr('data-surname'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="org-list">
  <li class="org-list-item">
    <span class="surname">AA</span>  <span class="name">John</span>
  </li>
  <li class="org-list-item">
    <span class="surname">AB</span>  <span class="name">John</span>
  </li>
  <li class="org-list-item">
    <span class="surname">AC</span>  <span class="name">John</span>
  </li>
  <li class="org-list-item">
    <span class="surname">BA</span>  <span class="name">John</span>
  </li>
  <li class="org-list-item">
    <span class="surname">BB</span>  <span class="name">John</span>
  </li>
  <li class="org-list-item">
    <span class="surname">CA</span>  <span class="name">John</span>
  </li>
  <li class="org-list-item">
    <span class="surname">CB</span>  <span class="name">John</span>
  </li>
  <li class="org-list-item">
    <span class="surname">CC</span>  <span class="name">John</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And if you opt to use jQuery Data Attribute, You can access the value of the DOM by,

```
$('li.org-list-item[data-surname]').each(function (i, elem){
 console.log($(elem).data('surname'));
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I only need to add letter data-surname="A" to a <li> with surname AA or data-surname="B" to a <li> with surname BA, not for every item in list. Do you know how to filter that?

Comment: @user2406735 Check my updated answer. Basically `$elem.text()` returns a string. And if you just want to get the initial, you can just access the first character of the string by using `[0]`.

Comment: Thank you for the update, but i wouldn't like to have data attributes on other li item, as i will use them to show the index for those surnames, so only the first of those surname should have data attribute

Comment: @user2406735 Please check my updated answer. Ah I get it, are you using it as for user to scroll to specific surname?

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect! Exactly, as the user scroll he will see the letter as index and i will set an anchor as well

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick function which will help you.

```
var selector = 'ul.org-list-item li span.surname'
Array.prototype.slice.call(
    document.querySelectorAll(selector)
).forEach(function(item) {
    var firstLetter = item.textContent.slice(0,1);
    item.parentElement.setAttribute('data-surname',firstLetter);
});
```

Info:

- **[This Function Fiddled](https://jsfiddle.net/BnPck/qt2txk64/)**
- [document.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)
- [Array.prototype.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)
- [Node.textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)
- [Node.parentElemnt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/parentElement)
- [String.prototype.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice)
- [element.setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you create a fiddle, or allow to run a code snippet, as i can't get this to work. Thanks

Comment: @user2406735 Added Fiddle ;)